# How do I retrieve metadata from the Wordpress Media Gallery?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the Wordpress Media Library, when you add a piece of media, you're invited to also add other 'metadata': Title, Caption, Alternate Text, and Description.

Using `get_the_title()` will return the title, but trying `get_the_caption()` simply breaks the page.

How do I get this data, or metadata on the page. I've also tried using `wp_get_attachment_metadata()`, which returns an array. Does anyone know what values are in this array? I know it has height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this metadata is stored to the `wp_posts` table.  For example, the caption for a photo is in column `post_excerpt`.  Since the title column is `post_title`, you might want to try the same naming convention and try a call to `get_the_excerpt()`.  Here are the other names of the columns in the `wp_posts` table

post_author     post_date   post_date_gmt   post_content    post_title  post_excerpt    post_status     comment_status  ping_status     post_password   post_name   to_ping     pinged  post_modified   post_modified_gmt   post_content_filtered   post_parent     guid    menu_order  post_type   post_mime_type  comment_count

Hope this helps

Comment: I like your thinking. Unfortunately what that returns is the except for the parent post -- in this case I am using the media as an attachment to a standard post. get_the_title gives back the title of the attachment, but get_the_excerpt returns the parent post, even if I explicitly use the exact id of the attachment.
Thanks though--voted up for conceptual clarity (it *should* work the way you think it should!) and detail in the answer.